# Calling a function in another class Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, swift3

I need to call this function. I need to receive the user `identityString`. How can i go about doing this?

```
class GeneralChatroom: UIViewController, 
                       UITableViewDataSource, 
                       UITableViewDelegate, 
                       UITextFieldDelegate, 
                       UITextViewDelegate {

    //Get Data of current cell that has been tapped
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {    
        let userIdentityString = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].cellUserId

        print("Uid of cell Data: " + userIdentityString!)
        print("section: \(indexPath.section)")
        print("row: \(indexPath.row)")
    }

     func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")

    //Transform Data From ^ to load at the bottom
    tableView.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: 1,y: -1);
    cell?.contentView.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: 1,y: -1);
    cell?.accessoryView?.transform = CGAffineTransform (scaleX: 1,y: -1);

    //Set username label to display username
    let usernameLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
    usernameLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].username

    //Set mesage TextView Label to display message in textView
    let messageLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(5) as! UITextView
    messageLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].message

    //TO DO: dont know if this actually works prob can delete
    messageLabel.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: false)


    //initialize UI Profile Image
    let imageView = cell?.viewWithTag(3) as! UIImageView

    //Make Porfile Image Cirlce
    imageView.layer.cornerRadius = imageView.frame.size.width/2
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true

    //Set timeStampLabel to current time AGO
    let timeStampLabel = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UILabel
    timeStampLabel.text = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].timeStamp
    timeStampLabel.numberOfLines = 0


    //Loading and change of Usesrs profile image on chat cell
    let userProfileChatImage = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].photoURL

    //Load profile image(on cell) with URL & Alamofire Library
        let downloadURL = NSURL(string: userProfileChatImage!)
        imageView.af_setImage(withURL: downloadURL as! URL)

    return cell!
}

}
```

But I need to call that function in a different class to get the `userIdentityString`. How can I do this? I need to call it in the Image Tapped function.

```
class GeneralChatroomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // You must to use interaction enabled
        profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(_:))))
    }

    func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        //first you need to call the function that reads the cell. Recieve the UID
        print("image tapped")
    }
}
```

maybe this will be more clear

```
func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let userIDString = GeneralChatroom.tableView(userIdentityString: userIdentityString)

        print(userIDString)

        //first you need to call the function that reads the cell. Recieve the UID
        print("image tapped")


    }



func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> String{

        let userIdentityString = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].cellUserId

        print("Uid of cell Data: " + userIdentityString!)
        print("section: \(indexPath.section)")
        print("row: \(indexPath.row)")

        //1.) If imageView touch is deteected
        //2.) Segua to new view controller by passing in the string UID(userIdentityString) of the cell
        //3.) Get database information based on the UID that is added(look at prevous methods)
        //      -might have to call this function and use separeate function
        //4.) Output data from database Users to represent a user profile



        //All you have to do is pass a UID (Check other Database methods to send UID)

        return userIdentityString!

    }
```

Comment: Do you have that data at the time you are creating the cell? Why not just create a property to store it on on the actual cell when its created so its always available.

Comment: can you show me an example?

Comment: Well first the function you are trying to call is a delegate function. That is called automatically so calling it manually may have unforeseen values available to you. You are using storyboards it looks like so I am not too familiar with that but I would populate that value on the cell in `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {` delegate function which is called every time a cell is created in the table when a view uses UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource.

Comment: Is that clear or do you need more info? I could throw together an answer with code if you want but I feel like my answer would lead in a different direction than what you are asking and would be off topic since I am not going to answer on how to call a function in another swift class.

Comment: I need an exact example i dont get what your trying to say

Answer (score 0):

OK, as I stated in my comment this answer is not about calling another function from a swift class because you are trying to call a delegate function. I am not sure it can be guaranteed that function will have the expected value if called manually. What I would do is create a property on your `TableViewCell` to hold the `userId`.

```
class GeneralChatroomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var textViewHeight: NSLayoutConstraint!

    // User Id
    var userId: String?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        // You must to use interaction enabled
        profileImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        profileImageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(imageTapped(_:))))
    }

    func imageTapped(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        //first you need to call the function that reads the cell. Recieve the UID
        print("image tapped")
        if let uid = self.userId {
            // Do whatever you want with userId
        }
    }
}
```

So I added an optional userId property on the TableViewCell. In order to populate that we will do it in the `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {` delegate function. I am not sure what yours looks like since you didn't provide that code so I am just going on what it generally looks like and what your GeneralChatroomTableViewCell is.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(GeneralChatroomTableViewCell.self), for: indexPath) as! GeneralChatroomTableViewCell
    (cell as! GeneralChatroomTableViewCell).userId = generalRoomDataArr[indexPath.row].cellUserId
    return cell
}
```

This function is called whenever a cell is being created for display in the table. So now on creation of the cell we set the `userId` so that its always available for us whenever we need it.

And as stated in the comment above this is only useful if that data is available at the time of creation of the cell.

Comment: Thats not going to work for me I need to call the function somehow as i stated above. I cannot do that. Im sorry i didnt post all my code.

Comment: You can manually call the function but you will need to provide the indexPath of the cell you want. Is there a reason you can't do the above? Without all the code its hard to know everything going on in your Table delegate. If I understood your limitations I could provide a better solution.

Comment: All i have to do is get the userIdentity String over to the imageTapped function.

Comment: So why does the proposed solution not work? If all you have to do is get it there I presented a viable solution to achieve that but you said it doesn't work for you. Why doesn't it work? If I knew why it didn't work I could help with a solution that does.....

Comment: Also that function you are trying to call doesn't return anything so I am not sure what use it will be in "getting the user id". My solution puts it right where you want it. What you want to do will not work.

Comment: I don't understand. What is the point to `GeneralChatroomTableViewCell ` if you are not using it? What cell do you register to the table in your ViewController?

Comment: I added more sudo code on the buttom to make what im trying to do more clear.

Comment: But you can't change the signature of the delegate method like that and just make it return a string. It will stop working.